# Playwright Tests run locally, but timeout on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to test a React app with Playwright. Setup and all tests run flawless on local, but in CI pipeline they timeout constantly despite the very generous timeout of 30.000 ms (I've also tried higher)

There is some flaw with navigation, as it seems:

```
Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded while running "beforeEach" hook.

  3 |
  4 | test.describe("Step 5 Sluice Tests", () => {
> 5 |   test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    |        ^
  6 |     await page.goto(`http://localhost:5173/projects/load?ip=${test_param_id}`);
  7 |     await page.waitForURL("http://localhost:5173/steps/1");
  8 |     await page.setViewportSize({ width: 2560, height: 1297 });

Error: page.waitForURL: Navigation failed because page was closed!
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for navigation to "http://localhost:5173/steps/3" until "load"
  navigated to "http://localhost:5173/steps/1"
  navigated to "http://localhost:5173/steps/2"
============================================================
```

### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

playwright:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
  script:
    - npm install
    - npx playwright install --with-deps chromium
    - npm run test:e2e # this is just a shortcut for "npx playwright test"
  artifacts:
    when: always  
    paths:  
      - playwright-report/  
      - test-results/  
    expire_in: 30 days
    untracked: true
```

FYI: using "vanilla" react with Vite as a build tool/dev server

### Playwright config:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  // Look for test files in the "tests" directory, relative to this configuration file.
  testDir: "e2e",
  testIgnore: "e2e/todo/**",

  timeout: 30000,

  // Run all tests in parallel.
  fullyParallel: true,

  //   // Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code.
  //   forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,

  //   // Retry on CI only.
  // retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,

  //   // Opt out of parallel tests on CI.
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

  // Reporter to use
  reporter: "html",

  outputDir: "test-results",

  use: {
    // Collect trace when retrying the failed test.
    trace: "on-first-retry",
    screenshot: "only-on-failure",
  },
  // Configure projects for major browsers.
  projects: [
    // Setup project
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
        storageState: "playwright/.auth/keycloak.json",
      },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
  ],
  // Run your local dev server before starting the tests.
  webServer: {
    command: "npm run start",
    url: "http://localhost:5173",
    reuseExistingServer: true,
  },
});
```

As mentioned, tests run without issue on a local machine. From what I can tell in the screenshots, the project is being loaded correctly, so I suspect there is no backend/API-connection issue. I also turned on logging to console, so eventual API errors would pop up there.

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnkurParihar sorry for the late reply. I found a solution, but I don't remember all the details. Also left that job in August. As far as I can remember, the screenshots from the branch that was running the tests weren't being updated from clearing the runners cache. Try to clean the screenshots folder, then push the empty folder and run the tests once on CI. The test will fail but the subsequent tests should be fine. Also, always set the resolution to a fixed value, that's where a lot of my pixel errors came from

Comment: Okay, thank you! @Niko

Comment: I know this is old but for others that come across this, you should set the desired tag of the playwright image based on your CI runner OS and playwright version. See https://playwright.dev/docs/docker#image-tags